Importing CpsExtract for API request of IPUMS data
How do I properly import CpsExtract to use it to define my IPUMS sample with Python?
Here are the steps I followed per this tutorial https://v1.developer.ipums.org/docs/workflows/create_extracts/cps/:

Installed ipumspy
Imported pandas and ipumspy
From ipumspy I tried importing IpumsApiClient and CpsExtract but dir(ipumspy) indicates that CpsExtract is not an importable class

Code:
import pandas as pd
import ipumspy
from ipumspy import IpumsApiClient, CpsExtract

Output:
ImportError: cannot import name 'CpsExtract' from 'ipumspy' (c:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\ipumspy\__init__.py)

Code:
dir(ipumspy)

Output:
['ABC',
 'Any',
 'ApiVersionWarning',
 'BaseExtract',
 'Codebook',
 'Dict',
 'IpumsApiClient',
 'IpumsApiException',
 'IpumsExtractNotSubmitted',
 'IpumsObject',
 'List',
 'MicrodataExtract',
 'ModifiedExtractWarning',
 'Optional',
 'Sample',
 'TimeUseVariable',
 'TransientIpumsApiException',
 'Type',
 'Union',
 'Variable',
 '__builtins__',
 '__cached__',
 '__doc__',
 '__file__',
 '__loader__',
 '__name__',
 '__package__',
 '__path__',
 '__spec__',
 '__version__',
 'abstractmethod',
 'annotations',
 'api',
 'core',
 'dataclass',
 'ddi',
 'define_extract_from_json',
 'exceptions',
 'extract',
 'extract_from_dict',
 'extract_to_dict',
 'field',
 'inspect',
 'json',
 'requests',
 'save_extract_as_json',
 'types',
 'warnings'
]

What is another way to define my Cps extract? MicrodataExtract only works for ACS data.
